# File served from a subdirectory in public folder references from root rather than subdirectory (Next 14)

Tags: next.js

I've taken the following steps:

1. `npx create-next-app` with version 14.1.0.
2. Add two files to the public directory under `test`, `index.html` and `index.js`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Document</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
console.log("Hi! This script loaded successfully");
```

I have also modified `next.config.js` to have the following contents.

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    async rewrites() {
        return {
         fallback: [
           {
             source: '/:path*',
             destination: '/:path*/index.html',
           },
         ],
       }
      },
};

export default nextConfig;
```

For clarity the structure is as follows

```
/
  /public
    /test
      - index.js
      - index.html
... autogenerated create-next-app files
```

As expected, `/test/index.html` correctly references the file `/test/index.js` and logs to the console "Hi! This script loaded successfully". However, in the case of navigating to `/test`, the file is referenced as `/index.js`, checking the root of public for a file that does not exist. (GET http://localhost:3000/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)).

Is there any intuition on why rewrites behave in this way with regards to referencing files in directories?

Comment: I'm not sure if this conflicts with Next's way of doing things, but I believe the plain webpack way would be to add `"homepage": "test/"` in package.json